# Apply Angular material 2 lighter/darker color to component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am playing around the material theme 
where there is a option to select primary,accent and warn like below

```
$candy-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-indigo, 500, 50, A200);
$candy-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, A200, A100, A400);
$candy-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);

$candy-app-theme: mat-light-theme($candy-app-primary, $candy-app-accent, 
$candy-app-warn);

 @include angular-material-theme($candy-app-theme);
```

in my html

```
<md-toolbar class="mat-primary">
<!-- above line works perfectly -->
<md-toolbar color="primary">
<!-- above line works perfectly (both are getting 500)-->
<md-toolbar class="mat-primary-lighter">
 <!-- need some kind of implementation to access the weight 50(lighter) or 
A200 (darker)-->
<div class="mat-primary">
 <!-- above is not working on general div bit it should work as it is 
  general class-->
```

Is there a way to generate this functionality without using something in scss like

```
.someClass { background:mat-color($mat-indigo, 50) }
```

Comment: Only other option is to create an entire new theme. The range of light-dark-normal are for built in animations and those colors and aren't for specific application. (That's assuming your scss was referring to using `@mixin` https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)

Comment: Yeah at them moment, your current workaround is going to be the most lightweight. As @Z.Bagley mentioned, an additional theme is the way to go for an easier, more future-proof solution. Additionally, if you're only going to do this for a handful of components, you don't need to generate an entire new theme, but only a subset of one (see [Theming only certain components](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#theming-only-certain-components))